# How to detect unsave changes and show warning message of previous row in angular ui grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

The scenario is My UI has the grid table on the top and edit row on the bottom. If the user clicks on row1 for example then the information of row1 is displayed on the bottom as form controls. User has an option to make the change for row1 and hit save. But if the user makes the changes in row1 but not save it and goes to row2, I want to show confirm dialog. If use click Yes, the row will be check. But if user click No, the row2 won't be checked.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example: https://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/ but in short here is how I did something similar in my project.

```
if (confirm("Do you want to save?")) {
      //Save the data
}
else
{
     //don't save
}
```